# vagrant port forwarding error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

first timer here but have been lurking for years:) usually i can find the answer to my troubles here but nto today:)
I have the following vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.define :webserver do |webserver|
   webserver.vm.box = "vagrant-centos-base.box" 
   webserver.vm.box_url = "http://127.0.0.1/vagrant-centos-base.box"
   #webserver.memory = "512"
   webserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.2.0.10"
   #webserver.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host 80
   webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: "443", host "443"# , protocol: "tcp"
   webserver.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
   end 
    webserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo hostname webserver
    SHELL
    #webserver.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    #   ansible.playbook="playbook.yml"
    #end
end

    config.vm.define :appserver do |appserver|
   appserver.vm.box = "vagrant-centos-base.box"
   appserver.vm.box_url = "http://127.0.0.1/vagrant-centos-base.box"
   #appserver.memory = "1024"
   appserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.2.0.11"
   appserver.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
     #vb.customize ["createhd", "--filename", "disk.vmdk", "--size", "1024"]
     #vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", 1, "--device", 0, "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "disk.vmdk"]
     #vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk0.vdi"]
   end 
   appserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo hostname appserver
    SHELL
end
```

end

when i try to issue vagrant up i get the following error:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ...ort", guest:
>   "443", host "443", protocol: "tcp" ...                               ^
>   if i comment out the protocol part i get a bit of a different one
>   then: : syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or
>   '{' or '(' ...ded_port", guest: "443", host "443"# , protocol: "tcp"
>   ...                               ^

I am lost at this point. I have tried all types of configs but non allow me to start the vm with port forwarding.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Options' section of the Vagrant [Forwarded Ports](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) documentation, it says that `guest` and `host` are both `int` type. Try removing the quotation marks (`"`) from around those variables.

My understanding is that vagrant will not automatically convert from `string` to `int` ([for example](https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt/issues/525)).

Comment: thank you for the reply, I tried that as well, then i get the following error: 15: syntax error, unexpected t
INTEGER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
           webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host 443

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue, I missed the : after defining the host portion of the port forwarding statement. It is all working now. Thank You!